# how to use a list of column names to get the indices of each column in python

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I have a list of column names and a csv file. I want to implement a function that reads the csv to return X (13 attributes as listed in x_col_names) and y (the corresponding final grade). X: numpy array: shape = [N, D], y: numpy array: shape = [N]. The data is delimited with

```
def load_student_data(filename):

X, y = None, None

X = np.empty((395,13))
y = np.empty((395,))
rows = []
with open(filename) as file:
  data = csv.reader(filename)
  for row in file:
    rows.append([row])
  arr = np.array(rows)
  print(arr)

return X, y
```

I tried this code but it didn't work. I think my logic is flawed. Also, I have no way to get the index of the columns because the only way I found was using pandas which I am not allowed to use. I am only entitled to csv, numpy and math.

I should get

1 14 4

6 5 6

(395, 13) (395,)

but the only output I got correct was the last one. I know I have not defined my X and y because I'm having difficulty and am still working on it. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: `genfromtxt` is a numoy csv reader.  You can specify columns by number (not name).  You can also load it as a structured array, and select fields by name.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. That's why I was looking for a method to get the index of columns using their names that doesn't require the usage of pandas.

Comment: To get the index of columns you have to read the column header line yourself, and find the names in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a small example file, and demonstrate the results.  It does't need to be the full 395 rows and 14? columns.

For now I'm just going to comment on the code

```
def load_student_data(filename):
    X, y = None, None
    X = np.empty((395,13))    
    y = np.empty((395,))
```

Why did you define `X,y` twice?  Do you understand what `empty` does?  It is not the same as the following list `[]`.

```
    rows = []
    with open(filename) as file:
          data = csv.reader(filename)
          for row in file:
              rows.append([row])
```

You open the `file`, but pass `filename`, not `file` to the `reader`.  What's the logic there?  You aren't doing anything with `data`!

So far I think `rows` will just be the same as doing `rows=file.readlines()`, a list of strings, one per line.

```
          arr = np.array(rows)
          print(arr)
    return X, y
```

So `arr` is an array of strings, just an array version of `rows`.  `X,y` are still the values you created with `empty`.

In a comment I suggested using `np.genfromtxt`, but that will require doing some reading, and testing with smaller files.  But it shouldn't be hard to read the csv with just the `readlines`, or with the help of the `reader`.  If doing that, I'd forget about `numpy` for the moment, and focus on reading and parsing individual lines.  Hint - string `split` is widely used to separate the columns in a line.

The problems with the code suggest you haven't paid much attention to details, and still have a limited grasp of Python.